# Validate a Schematron Schema with abstract rules fails with xmllint

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, xmllint, schematron

I am trying to validate a simple schematron with abstract rules using

- xmllint --version:
- xmllint: using libxml version 20900

The XML given is a simplified example Schematron File from a tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2"
xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">


<sch:title>This is an example schema for the Building Projects XML language.</sch:title>
<sch:pattern id="construction">
    <sch:rule context="house">
        <sch:assert test="count(wall) = 4">A house should have 4 walls</sch:assert>
        <sch:report test="not(roof)">The house is incomplete, it still needs a roof</sch:report>
        <sch:assert test="builder">An incomplete house must have
            a builder assigned to it</sch:assert>
        <sch:assert test="not(owner)">An incomplete house cannot have an owner</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
<sch:pattern id="completed">
    <sch:rule context="house">
        <sch:assert test="count(wall) = 4">A house should have 4 walls</sch:assert>
        <sch:report test="roof">The house is incomplete, it still needs a roof</sch:report>
        <sch:assert test="owner">An incomplete house must have an owner</sch:assert>
        <sch:assert test="not(builder)">An incomplete house doesn't need a builder</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
<sch:pattern id="admin">

    <sch:rule abstract="true" id="nameChecks">
        <sch:assert test="firstname">A <name/> element must have a first name</sch:assert>
        <sch:assert test="lastname">A <name/> element must have a last name</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>

    <sch:rule context="builder">
        <sch:extends rule="nameChecks"></sch:extends>
        <sch:assert test="certification">A <name/> must be certified</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
    <sch:rule context="owner">
        <sch:extends rule="nameChecks"></sch:extends>
        <sch:assert test="telephone">An <name/> must have a telephone</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
    <sch:rule context="certification">
        <sch:assert test="@number">Certification numbers must be recorded in the number attribute</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

What i do now is a:

```
xmllint --noout --schematron mySchema.schema ToVerify.xml
```

And I get the error message:

mySchema.schema:26: element rule: Schemas parser error : rule has no context attribute
--> this is:

mySchema.schema:32: element extends: Schemas parser error : Expecting an assert or a report element instead of extends
--> this is: 
mySchema.schema:36: element extends: Schemas parser error : Expecting an assert or a report element instead of extends
Schematron mySchema.schema failed to compile

As this is only a problem with the newer stuff like "abstract" rules ( abstract patterns do work ...) I assume the libxml Version does not have the capability to transform / resolve / preprocess this into stuff it can handle.

So I found preprocessors to expand abstract elements:
iso_abstract_expand.xsl (for iso Schematron xslt2)

But xsltproc will not preprocess the file either with

```
xsltproc iso_abstract_expand.xsl mySchema.schema > somefile.schema
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there someting wrong with my Schema (I assume that no, but hell who knows...).
2. What is my misconeption of xmllint? Am I completly not getting something?
3. What is the correct way to either directly validate with xmllint or preprocess via xsltproc

I am sorry if this all sounds pretty confused, but I found a plethora of hints on using abstract elements but they never only mentioned on how to then test them / compile them with xmllint.

Comment: I know this is an old question, perhaps you will still see this? What do you mean by "xsltproc will not preprocess the file"? Do you get an error? Can you show this error message? Did you take `iso_abstract_expand.xsl ` from a TEI repository?